# Python av play file in infinite loop

Tags: python, aiortc, pyav

Using https://pypi.org/project/av/ trying to open file for infinite playback.
But the cycle ends with the last frame.

After searching and reading manuals, test code looks as follows:

(Note: these options are expected to be passed down to `aiortc.contrib.media.MediaPlayer` and work similarly):

```
import av
av.open(file="file.mp4", options={"fflags": "+genpts", "loop": "-1"})
for frame in media.decode():
    print(frame)
```

Question: What should be the `options` (and if it is possible) to play file in infinite loop? (NOT just once)

Comment: `media` is not defined in your code example

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://aiortc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#media-sources), you create a `MediaPlayer` using the parameter `loop=True`

```py
from aiortc.contrib.media import MediaPlayer

player = MediaPlayer(file="file.mp4", options={"fflags": "+genpts"}, loop=True)
```

You don't need to call `PyAV` yourself. It is done in `MediaPlayer` (see [source code](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/d7fe37f42e66f5919a4c3a997777b54713012ef7/src/aiortc/contrib/media.py#L305-L307)).